# C++ Binary Literal

Tags: c++, binary, c++14

I know that **Binary Literal** in C++ is standardized from **C++14**.

However, although I fix the `std` as `c++11`, it works well. Because actually, I expected an error. The following is my code which I expected an error.

```cpp
int main(){
  int a = 0b1010; // an error is expected
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Also, I have compiled and executed the above file with the following command.

```sh
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall main.cpp -o runfile
./runfile
```

What is the reason that an expected result does not come out? Is there something that I've got wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect an error with that code?? And which one specifically?

Comment: Because binary literal is not standardized before C++14. So, I thought that it would be an error in C++11 with g++.

Comment: The C++ compiler that is part of GNU GCC (i.e., `g++`) has a lot of extensions to C++.  Some of those innovative extension became adopted into the C++ standard itself.  Most compilers provide extensions (often to facilitate interop with the platform and it's APIs), so having extensions — including retro-features of later C++ standard — isn't unique to GNU GCC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Binary literals have been a compiler extension in GCC long before C++14 standardized them. You can compile with `-pedantic` to warn on extensions and `-pedantic-errors` to elevate those specific warnings to errors:

```
<source>:3:11: error: binary constants are a C++14 feature or GCC extension
    3 |   int a = 0b1010; // an error is expected
      |           ^~~~~~
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It was an extension in GCC. It helped me!